# Syntax Error when I try to create trigger in mysql

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to create an trigger for an audit log, where after an insert into `manageMemberLog` and the `action` column is equal to `CREATE`, then insert the associate columns of `users` table and then grab the select the newly created row and grab the userID and then insert the rest of the data into profile, but I get this error msg when I tried to submit the query.

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 9`

Line 9 = END IF;

I tried carefully re-typing what I wrote but same error msg.

**UPDATE**: used the formatting and it says `WHERE userID = @newUserID` is the error, which i still don't understand as I grab the data from select and set the value into @newUserID.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER usersDB_ai AFTER INSERT
ON manageMemberLog 
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF NEW.action = 'CREATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, userName, email, pwd) VALUES (NEW.firstName, NEW.lastName, NEW.userName, NEW.email, NEW.pwd);
        SET @newUserID := (SELECT userID FROM users WHERE userName = NEW.userName AND email = NEW.email); 
        UPDATE profiles SET rankID = NEW.rankID WHERE userID = @newUserID;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The related tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) 

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `userCreated` AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO profiles (userID) VALUES(NEW.userID);
END
$$
DELIMITER ;


CREATE TABLE `profiles` (
  `profileID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rankID` int(11) NOT NULL,
   ...
)

CREATE TABLE `manageMemberLog` (
  `manageMemberLogID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manageDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `managerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` varchar(6) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `pwd` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `rankID` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

Can anyone help thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly Me, so what went wrong is I forgot to write "BEGIN" after FOR EACH ROW and does not involve any of the error that it says. Error messages are sometimes not reliable but I guess it did help by say `END`. A better error message is `you can't end when it never began.`

so correct query is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER usersDB_ai AFTER INSERT
ON manageMemberLog 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.action = 'CREATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, userName, email, pwd) VALUES (NEW.firstName, NEW.lastName, NEW.userName, NEW.email, NEW.pwd);
        SET @newUserID := (SELECT userID FROM users WHERE userName = NEW.userName AND email = NEW.email); 
        UPDATE profiles SET rankID = NEW.rankID WHERE userID = @newUserID;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```